# python.exe version 3.3.2 64 & 32 crash while creating .exe file on win 7 64 & 32 with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, windows-7

I have created a simple python application to detect changes in a set of words. Now I need an executable file of my script. Since I use python 3.3 the only way I found was using cx_Freeze. I have created my setup file according to the documentation presented by cx_Freeze website, and it seems to work. The thing is while it is creating the files in the bin folder python.exe crashes, there is only a windows error saying python.exe stopped working. In the lines printed to command prompt I can see that the crash has occurred after copying python33.dll. This I can confirm by comparing the copied file and the original file. Still, an exe file is created which also crashes when I run it. Tracing it, I found out that the exe file crashes when it tries to get a zipimporter instance, giving the error "cannot get zipimporter instance". I have a windows 7 64 bit, python 3.3.2 64 bit, and cx_Freeze 4.3.1 64 bit. I also have a windows 7 32 bit on a virtual machine with python 3.3.2 32 bit and cx_Freeze 4.3.1 32 bit. To my knowledge both Linux and windows users have this problem but only Linux users seem to have a solution! Maybe I didn't find the solution to my problem, but I have spent two days looking. I would be really grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally! A few days ago I managed to find a solution!!! The problem was with the icon. I don't know why but when I removed the icon from my setup file things got charmingly ok. But I needed the icon so after I created my exe file I packed everything in a rar file. I mean SFX rar file, and I set it's icon to what I wanted. So it is solved for me. Still, the error I was facing happens in many other cases, I have no solution for any of those.